# Powershell download to specific folder without knowing file name

Tags: powershell, url, download

I'm creating a Powershell script to download the latest version of a bunch of utilities. For some I know the URL and file name so this works:

```
$url = "https://download.sysinternals.com/files/SysinternalsSuite.zip"
$file = "SysinternalsSuite.zip"
$webclient.DownloadFile("$url","$storageDir\$file")
```

For some I just know the URL. For these I just know how to open it in the browser and file file is downloaded to the browsers download location.

```
$url = "https://toolslib.net/downloads/finish/1-adwcleaner/"
Start-Process "chrome.exe" "$url"
```

Is there any way to find the name of the file that was downloaded so it can be moved to $storageDir?

Alternately, is there a way to temporarily change a browsers default download location from inside the script and change it back at the end of the script? I'm not locked to any specific browser?

Comment: Have a go at using `$(Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\temp" | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending)[0].FullName`, which returns the most recently written file in the directory specified after `-Path`